# Is there a thing such as a "Unbounded Self Type"?

Tags: scala

I'd like to define a `Renamable` trait, supporting some classes that needs a mutable name field. 
Here is my first shot at it:

```scala
trait Renamable {
    self =>
    var name:String = _

    def withName(name:String) = {
        self.name = name
        self
    }
}

class Person extends Renamable {
    def sayHello = println(s"Hello, i am $name")
}
```

My problem is that the `withName()` return type is inferred to `Renamable`, not allowing me to chain method calls like this:

```
new Person().withName("Julio").sayHello 
//Error: value sayHello is not a member of Renamable
```

I've read that i can have a self type annotation and use it as the return type, but i do not know in advance in which types that will be used. I'd like the return to be of the same as the class using the trait, unboundedly.

Can i has "unbounded self types"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `this.type` (probably `self.type` will work as well). The only valid value of this type is `this` and hence allows the call site to know that the returned value is the receiver of the call:

```
trait Renamable {
    var name:String = _

    def withName(name:String): this.type = {
        this.name = name
        this
    }
}
```